# trestle HTTP Origin header (https:..) . didn't match request.base_url (http:// )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am using Trestle Admin in Rails and have configured my server to accept SSL connections. In `localhost` it works perfectly but when I tried to move to production I received the following error:

```
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.5ms)
I, [...T16:52:04.341111]  INFO: Started POST "/admin/login" for 190.12.77.81 at 2019-03-11 16:52:04 +0000
I, [...T16:52:04.341928]  INFO: Processing by Trestle::Auth::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [...T16:52:04.342009]  INFO: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UpwtvP0sNUrNqQazOh9BiLEv0uuOi75shw/leYNDJrPC9jpv7Qv9ShzZvFslBakHO+NjTtJPQ7bphiMbaBXzKg==", "email"=>"admin@silbia.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
W, [...T16:52:04.342504]  WARN: HTTP Origin header (https://wog.uye.pe) didn't match request.base_url (http://wog.uye.pe)
```

HTTP Origin header (https://example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://example.com) rails

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a middleware:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'json'

class CloudflareProxy
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    return @app.call(env) unless env['HTTP_CF_VISITOR']

    env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] = JSON.parse(env['HTTP_CF_VISITOR'])['scheme']
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Use in `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.middleware.use CloudflareProxy
```

A reference for `CF-Visitor` header:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-

> CF-Visitor
>
> A JSON object containing only one key called scheme. The value is identical to that of X-Forwarded-Proto (either HTTP or HTTPS). CF-Visitor is only relevant if using Flexible SSL.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Heroku and Cloudflare for SSL.
The solution that worked for me is setting SSL to "Full" in Cloudflare.